# How to change All Styles in Navbar after actions

Tags: reactjs, styling, subtree

It's my component. It's work pretty well, but.

I have problem with Styling.
After scroll, the navbar setState and add NavbarScroll to Navbar.
How can I style all subtree elements from this component. 
I need to change, every elements & components from Menu Component:

- all Link (a) and hovers
- Logo path img
- buttons

  ```
  export class Navbar extends Component{
      constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
          this.state={Navbar: 'Navbar'}
        }

          componentDidMount() {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
          };

          handleScroll() {
              let Navbar = this.state.Navbar
               this.setState( {Navbar : 'Navbar ' + 'NavbarScroll' } )
       };


      render(){
          return(

              <div onScroll={this.handleScroll.bind(this)} className ={this.state.Navbar}>
                  <Container>
                      <Row>
                          <Col sm={{size:3,}}>Logo</Col>
                          <Col><Menu/></Col>
                      </Row>
                  </Container>
              </div>

          )
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: pass a state as props to Menu, and the check it inside the child.. and accordingly apply styles..

Comment: Ok, I should pass state after handleScroll() or before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass state to Menu like this:

```
<Menu navbarState={this.state.Navbar} />
```

Then in Menu component say for a button do:

```
<button className={props.navbarState} />
```

This adds apropriate class to  so you can use it further in your css:

```
button.Navbar {
   styles for normal navbar
}

button.Navbar.NavbarScroll {
   styles for scrolled navbar
}
```

This example works if your Menu is uncontrolled Component initiated as

```
const Menu = (props) => {
}
```

if it is a class like

```
class Menu extends React.Component
```

then you should add this before props:

```
<button className={this.props.navbarState} />
```

Comment: It's helpful answer. What should I do, when Navbar have 3 generations and need to pass state inside Menu child?

Comment: I see three options: 1. pass the state to all of them (simplest solution) 2. learn how to use context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html 3. implement handleScroll() inside Menu

Comment: It works ! How can I signal that the button does not inherit from the Navbar Scroll class?

Comment: It's funny, because, when i pass {this.props.navbarState} it's inherit, and i have multiply Navbar

Comment: Piotr, if you don't want <button> to have class "NavbarScroll" then I would do something with ternary operator like this: <button className={this.props.navbarState === "Navbar" ? "button_navbar" : "button_navbar scroll"} />, so if a state is just "Navbar" your button would have a class "button_navbar", but with scroliing additional "scroll" class would apply to your button